# Htaccess to 2 domains, change tecnology, change folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have this situation:
The first domain (Es: forniture.endomain.it - old site in English) will have to do a 301 in the sub-directory domain-specific www.301pointdomain.it (Eg: www.301pointdomain.it/en/).

The second problem is I have to do the 301 www.originaldomain.it in the sub folder for the Italian (www.301pointdomain.it/it/).
Just to complicate matters, there has been a change in technology from asp to php, so I should also make 301 to the new php pages ....
Both are going to point the domain www.301pointdomain.it but in the respective language folders to preserve the identity domain!

To clarify things:
1: http://forniture.olddomainenglish.it/commy/namepage.asp?id=1234 -> `www.301pointdomain.it/en/page.php?id=1234`

2: http://www.301pointdomain.it/commy/namepage.asp?id=1234 -> `www.301pointdomain.it/it/page.php?id=1234`

Obviously I need to keep the querystring but to change the asp pages to php!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On `forniture.endomain.it` put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forniture\.endomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.asp$ http://www.301pointdomain.it/en/$1.php [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

**On `www.originaldomain.it` put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.originaldomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.asp$ http://www.301pointdomain.it/it/$1.php [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```